# How precise are ESC's?

Tags: pwm, control, motor-controller

I was wondering about the precision of ESC's. Specifically can I ensure their output motor RPM from different ESC/motor pair is the same function of pwm, assuming I have accounted for the specific ESC/motor pair engagement pulse width? Engagement pulse width = the shortest duty cycle which spins the motor.

My controller outputs a signal with pulse width proportional to the desired propeller rate (plus engagement width). But sadly this isn't translating to actual propeller rate. In short om1=om2=om3=om4 does not translate to equal RPMs. My equations are

duty1=(int)((2000-min1)*om1/6000+.5f);

pulsewidth1=min1+duty1;

where duty1 is the additional duty cycle in microseconds, min1 (integer) is the engagement pulse width for ESC1/motor1 in microseconds, om1 (double) is the desired propeller rate (rad/s) and I assume 6000 is the max prop rate in rad/s.
pulsewidth1 is the final duty cycle of signal (500hz) sent to ESC1.

Would appreciate if anyone knows more details about precision of ESC's, or proper calibration, and can share them!

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Open loop controllers will vary according to friction, load, torque and RPM. Current feedback or better a tach feedback is best to get repeatable responses when margin is allowed for speed rate of change..

Comment: Do you know if controllers such as cc3d w/openpilot, or pixhawk etc. use those types of feedback? I was under the impression that brushless motor dynamics were much faster than the quadrotor's physical dynamics, so I didn't have to look at the electro dynamics side as long as the ESC's achieve the right speed fairly quickly.

Comment: I have a model in matlab which works amazingly, but it runs under the assumption that the motors achieve the desired speeds instantly.

Comment: Brush or brushless motors? PWM itself is imprecise but should achieve 1-2% or better consistency between channels. PWM-driven brushless may get close to this, but brushed motors add wear-dependent friction and contact resistance, I'd be surprised if they were better than 5% unless you measure their speed with an encoder to servo out the errors. I'd try adding some errors to your model and see how robust it is against them.

Comment: They are brushless, but that does give me the idea to look at the pulses on an oscilloscope to see how consistent the signals are. Thanks @BrianDrummond

Comment: As you mention "propellor" you'll find each prop delivers slightly different thrust at the same RPM, and that varies with incident wind too...